# Opencv findContour

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, contour

I am working on a project to detect wounds, the type of wounds are as follow in the attached named(original).

I had tried with the following method to detect the area of wound that is of interest. However, the result of the detection is not of what i want to achieved(see attached named(outputFromAboveMethod)). The final outcome i wish to achieve is in the attached named(WhatIWant)

Could anyone help me pls.

Code to the current method:

```
public class DetectTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Bitmap, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dlg.setMessage("Processing");
            dlg.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Mat mat = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);

            Mat rgbMat = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, rgbMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);

            Mat dilatedMat = new Mat();
            Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(7, 7));
            Imgproc.morphologyEx(rgbMat, dilatedMat, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

            //red
            Mat redMat = new Mat();
            Core.inRange(rgbMat, new Scalar(0, 0, 120), new Scalar(100, 100, 255), redMat);

            //find contour
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();

            Imgproc.findContours(redMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            double largest_area =0;
            int largest_contour_index = 0;

            for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
                double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
                if (contourArea > largest_area) {
                    largest_area = contourArea;
                    largest_contour_index = contourIdx;
                }
            }

            Imgproc.drawContours(mat, contours, largest_contour_index, new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 3);
            Bitmap outputImage= Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(mat, outputImage);

            return outputImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap outputImage) {
            imageview.setImageBitmap(outputImage);
            dlg.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

[originalImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5wEs.png)

[outputFromAboveMethod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc60N.png)

[WhatIWant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLFKT.png)

[afterConvextHull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKZBj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your code to draw the convex hull of the found contour pretty much gets you what you want. A convex hull is the 'outline' of the contour. Example:
[image]

This code takes the output of findContours() and creates a list of convex hulls.

```
    List<MatOfPoint> hullList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();
        Imgproc.convexHull(contour, hull);
        Point[] contourArray = contour.toArray();
        Point[] hullPoints = new Point[hull.rows()];
        List<Integer> hullContourIdxList = hull.toList();
        for (int i = 0; i < hullContourIdxList.size(); i++) {
            hullPoints[i] = contourArray[hullContourIdxList.get(i)];
        }
        hullList.add(new MatOfPoint(hullPoints));
    }
```

You can draw a convex hull with

`Imgproc.drawContours(drawing, hullList, index, color );`

Check this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html), it contains a working example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply i had implemented this into the code and it works, however, there is still some inaccuracy in the detection(it detects some of the pink areas outside the red which i don't want, see image"afterConvexHull" in the question), could you suggest how i can improve on the detection, thank you.

Comment: You could try tweaking the morphology of the contour you found: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html Another option is to use the convex hull as a mask. You can use that to create a new image that only has the part inside the hull. Then you can try to select only the pink or the not pinks parts and use a bitwise operation to remove the pink part from the mask http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/bitwise-and-or-xor-and-not.html The mask then has the final shape.